# Can't see network printer after switching from standard wireless access points to Linksys Velop Dual band system

Tags: wireless-networking, wired-networking

I have included a link to a Word doc with the details of the before and after installation below.

https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AADGiu_4QvODYeCh5JlwGq6sfduPywPvUMY

When you try and print to the network printer now it says that the printer is in an error state. The link light on the JetDirect is ON.

Any other questions please ask and thanks in advance for the assistance.

Thanks, Quiller

Answer (score 0):

The printer has an IP address of 192.168.254.xxx and has been set manually.

The printer must have an IP address of 192.168.1.xxx in order to be able to be used.

Set the new printer IP address manually to an address that is free, and update all the clients.

Comment: That was the printers IP address in the old system.  I've already changed the IP to 192.168.1.200.  However, I did manage to solve the problem by. . .

Solution:

I setup the print driver in Windows 10 using:
‘Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or host name’
I entered the printer IP address of 192.168.1.200

Once this printer was setup in windows, of each wired and wireless systems, they printed without error.